# Text encryption using 8 digit key

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to create a program that can encrypt a message of any length using an 8 number key.

So far I have these smaller codes that I a supposed to use to help complete this program

```
def code_char():
    c = str(input("Please enter a letter: "))
    key = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    output = ord(c) + key
    if 91 <= output <= 96 or 122 < output:
        encryption = ord(c)-26+key
        print(chr(encryption))
    else:
        print(chr(output))

code_char()
```

This encrypts a single letter ^

```
def code_char(letter,key):
    output = ord(letter) + key
    if 91 <= output <= 96 or 122 < output:
        encryption = ord(letter)-26+key
        print(chr(encryption))
    else:
        print(chr(output))

def code_block(word,key):
    output = str()
    for i in range(0,8):
        letter = word[i]
        key = str(key)
        number = key[i]
        number = int(number)
        output += str(code_char(letter,number))
    return (output)
```

This encrypts a string of 8 letters with an 8 number key ^

```
def isLetter():
    character = str(input("Please enter a character: "))
    letter = ord(character)
    if 65 <= letter <= 90 or 97<= letter <= 122:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

isLetter()
```

This checks if the character is a letter ^

The program must ignore any other characters other than letters.

Any help on how to implement these codes together?

EDIT

This is the code I have so far:

```
def isLetter(word, key):
    letter = word[i]
    length = len(word)
    for i in range(length):
        if 65 <= ord(length) <= 90 or 97<= ord(length) <= 122:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    if True:
        output = str()
        key = str(key)
        number = key[i]
        number = int(number)
        output += str(code_char(letter,number))
    return (output)

    if False: continue
    output = str()
    key = str(key)
    number = key[i]
    number = int(number)
    output += str(code_char(letter,number))
    return (output)

isLetter("asdfghjk", 16057381)
```

I am get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not sure why, any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you have *already* been given plenty of help in the form of functions you can use. Perhaps you can show some code that you yourself have written and describe the problems that you are having with it. We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have written these codes myself, I'm not sure on how to use the isLetter function and how to loop around the key, if the input string is longer than 8 letters

Comment: If you have written the codes yourself why describe them as "smaller codes that I am supposed to use to help complete this program". Supposed by who? Why use the word "help"? That wording was at best confusing. In any event -- one hint is to change `isLetter()` so that it *returns* either `True` or `False` rather than *prints* them. Functions that print are basically useless from the point of view of being able to use them as building blocks of other functions. As far as looping around -- use the `%` operator.

Comment: @JohnColeman They are codes from previous task that lead up to this bigger task, with regards to the isLetter(), if I dont want it to actually return a value but just check if it is a letter, and encrypt it if it is, or ignore it and move on if it isn't a letter, how would I be able to do this with what I have?

Comment: Your present `isLetter()` function is useless since there is no (easy) way to check what has just been printed. Change the line `print("True")` to `return True` and similarly for false. Then in your encryption function you can have lines like `if isLetter(c):` Think of it this way: you *print* something if you want a *human* to see it. You *return* something if you want the computer to "see" it.

Comment: Your code seems confused. Shouldn't `isLetter` take a single character rather than a whole string and a key? Don't try to do too much in one function.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not sure how to have the isLetter take just one character from the string and then move onto the next

Comment: Not meaning to sound rude, but perhaps you can see your instructor during their office hours. Comments are not meant for open-ended tutoring, nor is Stack Overflow a tutorial site. By the way -- `ord(length)` is undefined since `length` is an `int` rather than a character.